# Django’s admindocs: Abstract models not shown

Tags: django, django-admin

How do I register abstract models in django admin docs? Example:

```
class UserContent(models.Model):
    """All user content must inherit this model"""

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    moderated = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Why do that? Abstract models shouldn't have records.

Comment: I Want UserContent: "All user content must inherit this model" to be in admin DOCS :)